# Emacs saveplace save-place-alist to file when kill-buffer: Why do i get recursion depth problems with hook?

Tags: debugging, emacs

I have been using Emacs (at the moment 26.3) for quite a while (years). I always had

```lisp
(use-package saveplace
  :config
  (save-place-mode t))
```

in my `init.el`, which makes Emacs use `save-place-mode` (which comes with vanilla Emacs as `saveplace.el`) in order to remember the last position in file.

My Problem with *saveplace* is, that it keeps saving visited files and positions to a list called `save-place-alist` and only through a hook in `kill-emacs-hook` it dumps this list to default location `~/.emacs.d/places`. But it occurs quite often, that i forget or somehow not normally quit my emacs-daemon. So, the list will be lost.

My approach was to extract the function `save-place-alist-to-file` from `saveplace.el` and add it to the `kill-buffer-hook` so now, everytime i kill a buffer `save-place-alist` would be saved to disk. This is what my save-place config looks now:

```lisp
(defun my-save-place-alist-to-file ()
(interactive)
(save-place-to-alist)
  (let ((file (expand-file-name save-place-file))
        (coding-system-for-write 'utf-8))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Saved Places*")
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (when save-place-forget-unreadable-files
        (save-place-forget-unreadable-files))
      (insert (format ";;; -*- coding: %s -*-\n"
                      (symbol-name coding-system-for-write)))
      (let ((print-length nil)
            (print-level nil))
        (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer)))
      (let ((version-control
             (cond
              ((null save-place-version-control) nil)
              ((eq 'never save-place-version-control) 'never)
              ((eq 'nospecial save-place-version-control) version-control)
              (t
               t))))
        (condition-case nil
            ;; Don't use write-file; we don't want this buffer to visit it.
            (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file)
          (file-error (message "Saving places: can't write %s" file)))
        (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))))

(use-package saveplace
  :config
  (save-place-mode t)
  ;; (remove-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'save-place-to-alist)
  ;; (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'my-save-place-alist-to-file))
```

Everything i fine, as long as i dont modify the `kill-buffer-hook` by uncommenting the last to lines. The function `my-save-place-alist-to-file` works properly when called interactively. But when activate the hooks, literally everything brakes. First of all i can not kill buffers anymore. I get this error related to recursion depth:

```
progn: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size
```

The debugger says:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size")
  generate-new-buffer(" *temp*")
  pp-to-string((("/home/.../test.txt" . 33)))
  pp((("/home/.../test.txt" . 33)) #<buffer  *Saved Places*>)
  (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer)))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Saved Places*")) (delete-region (point-min) (point-max)) (if save-place-forget-unreadable-files (progn (save-place-forget-unreadable-files))) (insert (format ";;; -*- coding: %s -*-\n" (symbol-name coding-system-for-write))) (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer))) (let ((version-control (cond ((null save-place-version-control) nil) ((eq (quote never) save-place-version-control) (quote never)) ((eq (quote nospecial) save-place-version-control) version-control) (t t)))) (condition-case nil (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file) (file-error (message "Saving places: can't write %s" file))) (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))
  (let ((file (expand-file-name save-place-file)) (coding-system-for-write (quote utf-8))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Saved Places*")) (delete-region (point-min) (point-max)) (if save-place-forget-unreadable-files (progn (save-place-forget-unreadable-files))) (insert (format ";;; -*- coding: %s -*-\n" (symbol-name coding-system-for-write))) (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer))) (let ((version-control (cond ((null save-place-version-control) nil) ((eq ... save-place-version-control) (quote never)) ((eq ... save-place-version-control) version-control) (t t)))) (condition-case nil (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file) (file-error (message "Saving places: can't write %s" file))) (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))))
  my-save-place-alist-to-file()
  kill-buffer(#<buffer  *temp*-840370>)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1c65c75>)()
  pp-to-string((("/home/.../test.txt" . 33)))
  pp((("/home/.../test.txt" . 33)) #<buffer  *Saved Places*>)
  (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer)))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Saved Places*")) (delete-region (point-min) (point-max)) (if save-place-forget-unreadable-files (progn (save-place-forget-unreadable-files))) (insert (format ";;; -*- coding: %s -*-\n" (symbol-name coding-system-for-write))) (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer))) (let ((version-control (cond ((null save-place-version-control) nil) ((eq (quote never) save-place-version-control) (quote never)) ((eq (quote nospecial) save-place-version-control) version-control) (t t)))) (condition-case nil (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file) (file-error (message "Saving places: can't write %s" file))) (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))
  (let ((file (expand-file-name save-place-file)) (coding-system-for-write (quote utf-8))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Saved Places*")) (delete-region (point-min) (point-max)) (if save-place-forget-unreadable-files (progn (save-place-forget-unreadable-files))) (insert (format ";;; -*- coding: %s -*-\n" (symbol-name coding-system-for-write))) (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer))) (let ((version-control (cond ((null save-place-version-control) nil) ((eq ... save-place-version-control) (quote never)) ((eq ... save-place-version-control) version-control) (t t)))) (condition-case nil (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file) (file-error (message "Saving places: can't write %s" file))) (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))))
  my-save-place-alist-to-file()
  kill-buffer(#<buffer  *temp*-437350>)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1c65c35>)()
  pp-to-string((("/home/.../test.txt" . 33)))
  pp((("/home/.../test.txt" . 33)) #<buffer  *Saved Places*>)
  (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer)))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Saved Places*")) (delete-region (point-min) (point-max)) (if save-place-forget-unreadable-files (progn (save-place-forget-unreadable-files))) (insert (format ";;; -*- coding: %s -*-\n" (symbol-name coding-system-for-write))) (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer))) (let ((version-control (cond ((null save-place-version-control) nil) ((eq (quote never) save-place-version-control) (quote never)) ((eq (quote nospecial) save-place-version-control) version-control) (t t)))) (condition-case nil (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file) (file-error (message "Saving places: can't write %s" file))) (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))
  (let ((file (expand-file-name save-place-file)) (coding-system-for-write (quote utf-8))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Saved Places*")) (delete-region (point-min) (point-max)) (if save-place-forget-unreadable-files (progn (save-place-forget-unreadable-files))) (insert (format ";;; -*- coding: %s -*-\n" (symbol-name coding-system-for-write))) (let ((print-length nil) (print-level nil)) (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer))) (let ((version-control (cond ((null save-place-version-control) nil) ((eq ... save-place-version-control) (quote never)) ((eq ... save-place-version-control) version-control) (t t)))) (condition-case nil (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file) (file-error (message "Saving places: can't write %s" file))) (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))))
  my-save-place-alist-to-file()
...
```

I already did try a lot things to fix this. My first guess was, that the final call of `(kill-buffer (current-buffer))` would lead to the infinite recursion. But removing it does not help.

To summarize, my question is:
* Why and where does the infinite recursion happen?

Comment: It seems the code creates a temp buffer which when killed invokes the function again in its kill-buffer-hook. I guess the temp buffer is created to save the places. Maybe disable the hook inside the function?

Comment: @Drew alright, edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried what @choroba mentioned by adding a

```
(let 'kill-buffer-hook nil
...
)
```

around the whole part after `(save-place-to-alist)` which indeed removed the infinite recursion problem! But then another problem emerged: this hooked got called everytime i switched buffers, which-key popped up and down and in many more occasions. Everytime writing to `~/.emacs.d/places`. So this was not what i wanted.

Meanwhile I've found a convenient solution: adding the function *not* to the `kill-buffer-hook` *but* to `after-save-hook`. Which is sufficient for me :)

My final `save-place`-setup which works fine for me now looks like this:

```lisp
(defun my-save-place-alist-to-file ()
  (interactive)
  (save-place-to-alist)
  (let ((file (expand-file-name save-place-file))
        (coding-system-for-write 'utf-8))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Saved Places*")
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (when save-place-forget-unreadable-files
        (save-place-forget-unreadable-files))
      (insert (format ";;; -*- coding: %s -*-\n"
                      (symbol-name coding-system-for-write)))
      (let ((print-length nil)
            (print-level nil))
        (pp save-place-alist (current-buffer)))
      (let ((version-control
             (cond
              ((null save-place-version-control) nil)
              ((eq 'never save-place-version-control) 'never)
              ((eq 'nospecial save-place-version-control) version-control)
              (t
               t))))
        (condition-case nil
            ;; Don't use write-file; we don't want this buffer to visit it.
            (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file nil) ; 4th arg nil means: do not append!
          (file-error (message "Saving places: can't write %s" file))
          (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))))))

(use-package saveplace
  :config
  (save-place-mode t)
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-save-place-alist-to-file)) ; after-save-hook seems to be the best place for this
```